# how to get Time Machine backup overnight instead of every hour?

Tags: time-machine

My (older) iMac runs 24/7 and it seems like it's constantly doing Time Machine backups which slows down things considerably.  My wife is always complaining about beach balls.

Is there a way to configure Time Machine to do backups only in the wee hours of the morning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a nice looking piece of freeware worth trying called [Time Machine Editor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/) which looks like it'll do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use [TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/). Free. Doesn't say, but it works on Lion too.

> TimeMachineEditor is a software for Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard and Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard that lets you change the default one-hour backup interval of Time Machine.
>   You can change the interval or create a more sophisticated scheduling (see screenshot below).
>
> This is useful if you don’t need to backup every hour and don’t want
>   the performance penalty. This is also especially useful if you
>   manipulate lots of data within one hour as you would spend the whole
>   day backing up.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [TimeMachineScheduler](http://www.klieme.com/TimeMachineScheduler.html) for this purpose for quite some time now. You can set it up to make backups only at certain hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sync interval - you can in this link read how to do this: http://maketecheasier.com/change-your-time-machine-backup-interval/2009/06/05

The link also show a 3-part Time Machine Editor.